Can't Use Monaco-Editor and Gemini API in the same Electron js Application
I'm trying to make a AI integrated IDE in Electron js but I can't use Monaco-Editor and Gemini API at the same time.
Here is the codes
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>R-IDE</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <section class="mainapp">
        <nav style="-webkit-app-region: drag">

        </nav>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="resizable" id="file-manager">
                <button id="select-folder">Select Folder</button>
                <div id="tree-container"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="resizer" id="handle-left" data-resize="left"></div>
            <div class="resizable" id="code">
                <label id="file-name">File Name</label>
                <hr id="ayırac">
                <div id="editor"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="resizer" id="handle-right" data-resize="center"></div>
            <div class="resizable" id="chat">
                <div id="chat-main">
                </div>
                <div id="prompt-main">
                    <textarea id="prompt"></textarea>
                    <button id="send"><img src="icons/Email Send.png"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
<script type="module" src="script.js"></script>
<script src="loader.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="chatScript.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="jsTreeScript.js"></script>
</html>

jsTreeScript.js:
const button=document.getElementById('select-folder')
button.addEventListener('click', () =\> {
const input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'file';
input.webkitdirectory = true; // Klasör seçimi için
input.multiple = true;       // Çoklu dosya seçimi için
input.click();

  input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    const files = Array.from(event.target.files);
    const treeData = buildTreeData(files);

        // jsTree'yi oluştur
    $('#tree-container').jstree('destroy').jstree({
      core: {
        data: treeData
      }
    });

  });

    button.style.display="none";
});

// Dosya ve Klasör Yapısını Hiyerarşik Tree Data'ya Dönüştür
function buildTreeData(files) {
  const tree = [];

  files.forEach(file => {
    const pathParts = file.webkitRelativePath.split('/');
    let current = tree;

    pathParts.forEach((part, index) => {
      const existing = current.find(item => item.text === part);

      if (!existing) {
        const newNode = {
          text: part,
          state: { opened: true },
          children: []
        };

        if (index === pathParts.length - 1 && !file.type.endsWith('/')) {
          newNode.data = file; // Dosya nesnesini kaydet
        }

        current.push(newNode);
        current = newNode.children;
      } else {
          current = existing.children;
        }
    });
  });
    return tree;
}

// jsTree Tıklama Olayını Dinleme
let uzantı="";

var editor;

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  editor.layout(); // Pencere boyutu değiştiğinde editörü yeniden boyutlandırır
});


$('#tree-container').on('select_node.jstree', (e, data) => {
    const file = data.node.data;

    const label=document.getElementById("file-name");
    label.textContent=data.node.text;

    const dotIndex = data.node.text.lastIndexOf('.');
    
    // Eğer nokta bulunursa, noktadan sonrasını döndür
    if (dotIndex !== -1) {
        uzantı= data.node.text.substring(dotIndex + 1); // Noktadan sonrasını al

        switch(uzantı){
          case "js":
            uzantı="javascript"
            break;
          case "py":
            uzantı="python"
            break;
          case "cs":
            uzantı="csharp"
            break;
          case "rb":
            uzantı="ruby"
            break;
          case "ts":
            uzantı="typescript"
            break;
          case "rs":
            uzantı="rust"
            break;
          case "md":
            uzantı="markdown"
            break;
          case "kt":
            uzantı="kotlin"
            break;
          case "kts":
            uzantı="kotlin"
            break;
          case "txt":
            uzantı="plaintext"
            break;
          default:
            uzantı=uzantı
            break;
        }
    }
    
    else{
      uzantı= '';
      textarea.value="File can't be loaded"
    }

    if (file) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => {

          if(editor==null){
            require.config({ paths: { 'vs': 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/monaco-editor/0.34.0/min/vs' } });
            require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {

              monaco.editor.defineTheme('solarized-light', {
                base: 'vs',
                inherit: true,
                rules: [
                    { token: '', foreground: '586e75', background: 'e8e8e8' },
                    { token: 'comment', foreground: 'ABABAB' },
                    { token: 'keyword', foreground: '859900' },
                    { token: 'string', foreground: '2aa198' }
                ],
                colors: {
                    'editor.background': '#e8e8e8'
                }
            });
  
                editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('editor'),     {
                    value: event.target.result,
                    language: uzantı,
                    theme: 'vs-light',
                });

                monaco.editor.setTheme("solarized-light")
              });
          }
          else{
            const model = monaco.editor.createModel(event.target.result, uzantı);
            editor.setModel(model);
          }
        }

        reader.onerror = () => {
            textarea.value="File can't be loaded"
        };

        reader.readAsText(file); // Dosyanın içeriğini oku
    }
});

chatScript.js:
const { GoogleGenerativeAI } = require("@google/generative-ai");

const genAI = new GoogleGenerativeAI("myAPIKEY");

let history=[

]

const sendbtn=document.getElementById("send");

sendbtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
  messageDiv.classList.add("outgoing");
  messageDiv.innerText = prompttext.value;
  messagesContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
  history.push({role: "user", parts:[{text: prompttext.value}]})
  console.log(history)
  run()
})

const prompttext=document.getElementById("prompt");
const messagesContainer=document.getElementById("chat-main")

async function run() {
  // The Gemini 1.5 models are versatile and work with multi-turn conversations (like chat)
  const model = genAI.getGenerativeModel({ model: "gemini-1.5-flash"});

  const chat = model.startChat({
    history,
    generationConfig: {
      maxOutputTokens: 100,
    },
  });

  const result = await chat.sendMessage(prompttext.value);
  prompttext.value=""
  const response = await result.response;
  const text = response.text();
  history.push({role: "model", parts:[{text: text}]})
  const messageDiv = document.createElement("div");
  messageDiv.classList.add("incoming");
  messageDiv.innerText = text;
  messagesContainer.appendChild(messageDiv);
}

Those are my files Monaco-Editor is working but the gemini API gives this error:

Uncaught Error: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module '@google/generative-ai'. This is the first mention of this module!
at c.synchronousRequire (loader.js:8:6342)
at r (loader.js:9:2065)
at chatScript.js:1:32

But when I delete the loader.js file the Gemini API works but Monaco-Editor doesn't.
What should I do?
